# How 3rd party should authenticate with custom Apex REST API

Tags: apex, rest-api, authentication

When using `@RestResource` to create a custom REST API which is exposed externally using a public site.

How should the third party service (ESB) authenticate with Salesforce so that it can use the custom REST API?

Comment: You don't authenticate with the endpoint, but you authenticate your external application (ESB in this case) with Salesforce and then invoke the REST API.

Comment: @JayantDas thanks, I've updated the question so it's more clear what I am asking

Comment: I have added the reference to documentation on this topic which should help here.

Comment: Best practice for server-to-server calls is to use [JWT Bearer flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) in oAuth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any external app to be able to invoke a REST API in Salesforce, it needs to authenticate itself using OAuth 2.0. The answer to your question is very well explained in [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm)

> Before making REST API calls, you must authenticate the application user using [OAuth 2.0](https://oauth.net/).

In summary, you will need to:

1. Setup a Connected App
2. Use the client key/secret and utilize that from ESB to get the access token
3. Utilize the access token to invoke the REST APIs

The documentation link has further necessary information around configuring this.